# Unable to see the Windows Azure (Host in Cloud) option for VS2013 Professional version

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I installed VS2013 in my machine having the following details: OS Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

While creating a sample ASP.NET MVC 5 application I am unable to see the Windows Azure (Host in Cloud) option as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Can anyone help me to know is there any other component I am missing to install so that Windows Azure (Host in Cloud) option is visible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the very same problem. I fixed it by going to the Tools -> Extensions and Updates and chose to update all installed. Once the updates were applied the Azure Host in Cloud panel was back.

I had to go through this even though I had re-installed VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case it may have been a combination of the answer provided by Paul Mooney, but ALSO that I had selected .Net Framework 4 instead of 4.5+