# Visual Studio 2015 - Can't see Azure view and can't publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure, hosting, publish

I got a probleme with Visual Studio 2015 Community.

If I want to create a new project I get the same problem as described here (hosting in the cloud is not shown):

[Unable to see the Windows Azure (Host in Cloud) option for VS2013 Professional version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068135/unable-to-see-the-windows-azure-host-in-cloud-option-for-vs2013-professional-v)

The Azure SDK is installed and I tried the described solutions with multiple uninstall/install and repair of Visual Studio.

But also I got a further problem. When I want to publish an app to Azure (right click on the project -> publish) I can't see my subscriptions and get the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

[image]

Are there any ideas how I can fix the problems? I'm currently completly unable to publish to Azure.

In addition: I got this problem only on my companies notebook. My privat computer / visual studio worked immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+++SOLVED+++

Today a new error occured. I loaded a project and got the error:

"The ‘CctSharedPackage’ package did not load correctly. Restarting Visual Studio could solve the problem."

A short research directed me to this link which worked immediately:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2014/02/12/fixing-the-cctsharedpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly/

(System Control Panel -> Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft -> Change -> Repair)